# How can I use WordPress as a job board ? (but free)

Tags: themes, cms

I wish to use WordPress installation for a job board.  Looking online I found the following two posts that give a list of options:
http://www.wpmods.com/turn-wordpress-into-job-board/
http://skyje.com/2010/01/job-board-solutions-for-wordpress/

But all of the options (except 1) cost money.

Is there a free (good) solution for WP job board (theme/plugins) ?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want to do is add a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types) for a job posting. Take a look at [this example](http://thinkvitamin.com/dev/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/) custom post type which should give you a good template for creating a job post.

In the past (before 3.0) I have used the [Magic Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/) plugin to add a custom post type for "Jobs" by adding the fields I want for job posts.

Comment: +1, but not for the faint of heart :) I'm actually playing with those too, with some success.

Comment: Hi Artlung. First - thank you for answering.  Now, I am sure I can do it with the new custom posts (it does sound like the correct way), but I wonder how much support would the common themes have for this.  I would rather have something that someone gave much thought to. (and again, if possible, GPL/free :)  )

Comment: The issue Tal, is you might want to customize how things appear. So, what is an excerpt for a job post? And how do they appear in search results? I think you will end up having to customize how the job posts appear WHEREVER they appear. Because, what if you want to extend `the_title()` to be suffixed with [JOB] in your nav? There's a lot of considerations, and I don't think you can get around customizing your theme.

Answer (score 3):

You get what you pay for. I've used Templatic and DailyWP's job board themes (in your first link) and they're both very good.

I haven't seen a free theme that comes close to them as far as overall quality, payment integration, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Callan. I hope there are alternatives.  If not, I guess I will give them a shot